# How to write a transparent WebKit GTK application

Tags: webkit, gtk, xfce

I am trying to write a GTK application, which just contains a GTK WebKit view in it. I hope the WebKit view is transparent, so the window below could be viewed, this feature is intented.

I found the answer in "[Is it possible to render web content over a clear background using WebKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324923/is-it-possible-to-render-web-content-over-a-clear-background-using-webkit)" works on one of my PC, which is running Ubuntu with compiz, but does not work on another, which is running Debian with xfwm4. On xfwm4, it just shows a gray background when called `webkit_web_view_set_transparent`, when I did not call `webkit_web_view_set_transparent`, it just shows a white background. The testing HTML file is same on Ubuntu and Debian.

As far as I understand, to make the WebKit view transparent, I have to setup a compositing window manager.

To check whether my xfwm4 supporting compositing, I tried following code:

```
import gtk
import cairo

class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
__gsignals__ = {
    'expose-event': 'override'
    }

def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.set_app_paintable(True)
    # no window border
    self.set_decorated(False)

    # see if we can do transparency
    screen = self.get_screen()

    alphamap = screen.get_rgba_colormap()
    rgbmap   = screen.get_rgb_colormap()

    if alphamap is not None:
        self.set_colormap(alphamap)
    else:
        self.set_colormap(rgbmap)
        print 'sorry, no alpha channel available :('

    self.set_size_request(300, 200)

def do_expose_event(self, event):
    # we're going to draw on a temporary surface
    # then copy to the window surface
    # you can also draw directly on the window
    width, height = self.get_size()

    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
    ctx = cairo.Context(surface)

    # background is gray and transparent
    ctx.set_source_rgba(.7, .7, .7, 0.75)
    ctx.paint()

    # red border
    ctx.set_line_width(3.0)
    ctx.rectangle(0, 0, width, height)
    ctx.set_source_rgba(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, .75)
    ctx.stroke()

    # now copy to our window surface
    dest_ctx = self.window.cairo_create()
    # only update what needs to be drawn
    dest_ctx.rectangle(event.area.x, event.area.y, 
                       event.area.width, event.area.height)
    dest_ctx.clip()
    # source operator means replace, don't draw on top of
    dest_ctx.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
    dest_ctx.set_source_surface(surface, 0, 0)
    dest_ctx.paint()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    gtk.main()
```

This application shows a transparent bock with red border. So, I guess my Debian with  Xfwm4 (version 4.8.3-1) should support compositing.

Anyone know why my GTK application could not be transparent?

===============

update:
I found the problem is in libwebkit, not in window manager. The versions of libwebkit in these two systems are different, and I tried my application another xfwm4 environment, the transparency works.