# Is it possible to make a webkit webview transparent within the application like other gtk widgets?

Tags: python-3.x, webview, gtk, pygtk, webkit2

I am writing a simple application with Python3, Gtk3 and Webkit2. One of the elements is a webview, but I want the webview to be transparent to the background set for the parent container - in this case a Gtk.Paned in a Gtk.Box where the GtK.Box can optionally have a background image set.

Most of the solutions I've found out there give you a webview that is transparent to the screen/desktop. Like this solution:

- [Is it possible to render web content over a clear background using WebKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324923/is-it-possible-to-render-web-content-over-a-clear-background-using-webkit/1133455#1133455)

This is not quite what I want. Is there any way to choose what webview is transparent to? Or another approach that produces the desired result?

Comment: The approach with `set_transparent` works (e.g. with a GtkOverlay) but it's not available in WebKit2.

Comment: There is no particular reason to use WebKit2 over WebKit in my case. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: const webview = new WebKit2.WebView(); webview.set_background_color(new Gdk.RGBA()) worked for me in gjs

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but as far as I know it's not currently possible.